# Using PHP's Built-In Web Server with Symfony's Production Mode

Tags: php, symfony, php-builtin-server

I just created a new Symfony 3.4 application.  Per Symfony's docs, I can server my application using PHP's built-in web-server by running

```
php bin/console server:start
```

However -- this appears to run the application in development mode.  This means exception printing is on, the developer toolbar shows up, etc.

Is there a way to use the built-in web server with Symfony's production mode?  This isn't to serve an application to the public (which wouldn't be a good idea) but instead because I want to test an issue that may only crop up in production mode.

Comment: How about `php bin/console server:start --env=prod`?

Comment: You can manually edit `app_dev.php` to switch it to PROD. Comment out `Debug::enable()` and change it to `prod`, e.g., `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @revo -- however, that led to a *There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace* exception, and the server did not start.  Which is a weird error message, but [shoulder shrug emoji guy]

Comment: Ok what if you change the order `php bin/console --env=prod server:start`?

Comment: @revo same error. (Symfony 3.4 if it matters)

Comment: Just for info, the webserver bundle is only enabled for dev.  You can see that in AppKernel.php or bundles.php.  So specifying the environment is basically a dead end.  So you can fool around with app.php but what you really should do to get a proper test is to go ahead and configure an apache or nginx server for production testing.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of symfony's server command you can run PHP's built-in web-server directly with the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t web/ app.php
```

This assumes that you are currently in your project directory and that the `web/` directory hosts your `app.php` file.

`-t` denotes the document root. In this example that is `web/`.

`app.php` is specified as the router script and will handle your request.

[More info on PHP's built-in web server command](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Now when you go to `localhost:8000` it will be serving your Symfony project in `Production` mode.

This doesn't run the server in the background, but you can easily search google for how to do that.

Comment: for me this one works: `php -S localhost:8000 -t web/ web/app.php`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Symfony 4 you need to enable the server bundle for `all` environments in the `bundles.php` file. By default it's only turned on for `dev`.

```php
<?php

return [
    // ...
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you specify the `app.php` on the url you enter in the browser, so something like this

```
mysite.dev/app.php/login
```

Or

```
localhost:8000/app.php/login
```

By default it will automatically use `app_dev.php`

Answer (score 1):

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t web/ web/app.php
```

This worked for me.
Otherwise,this error will be thrown:
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'app.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I don't really see how your answer differ from the one accepted and answered two years ago. If you have something valuable to bring in to an existing answer, you'll have the privilege to comment on posts with when you have a little more réputation.